# Can we import images in Magento2 using URL via rest api

Tags: magento2

Currently, we can import images in Magento using Rest API where we need to provide base64 data.

We need to know can we import images in Magento 2 using image URL in rest API instead of sending base64 data?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a VERY old question, but the short answer is no.  (At least not without doing something fancy in the theme or a custom module/plugin).

You'll need to download the images and then re-pack them using base64.
You'll also need to include the mime type.